# how to Dual Boot Windows 10 and Windows Server WITHOUT INSTALLATION

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2012-r2, bcdedit, dualboot

Several internet sites describe how to *install* Windows Server as a second OS. This is **not** my case.

On the same PC I have a working drive with Windows 10 Pro and *another drive* with Windows Server 2012 R2 (+ Visual Studio 2017 + SQL Server 2017 + SharePoint 2016 ...). Both drives with MBR (not GPT). I can boot either one as a single system (drive).

I now want to add Windows Server as a Dual Boot option. This *used to work* as Dual Boot but was broken while experimenting with a new Ubuntu installation. My previously working Boot Manager/Loaders setup was:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {4c702cd7-4348-11e9-a123-a126b58ebe81}
displayorder            {current}
                        {23a79a8c-7591-11e8-a5b9-10c37b6b0c8f}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {4c702cda-4348-11e9-a123-a126b58ebe81}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {4c702cd7-4348-11e9-a123-a126b58ebe81}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {23a79a8c-7591-11e8-a5b9-10c37b6b0c8f}
device                  partition=S:
path                    \windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows Server 2012 R2
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=S:
systemroot              \windows
resumeobject            {23a79a8b-7591-11e8-a5b9-10c37b6b0c8f}
nx                      OptOut
detecthal               Yes
```

How can I re-establish (or repair) a working Dual Boot environment? ...obviously without installing a fresh Windows Server OS and all the ensuing work on it that followed.

**EDIT:**
In order to recover the Windows Server drive, I issued the following commands yesterday WITH **ONLY** THE Windows Server DRIVE INSTALLED in the PC:

```
bootrec /FixMbr
bootrec /FixBoot
bootrec /RebuildBcd
```

That made Windows Server bootable as a single drive again (and maybe broke the Dual Boot logic from the Windows 10 drive?)

**UPDATE:**
I booted the DVD prepared by Windows 10 with MediaCreationTool1909.exe:

```
>bootrec /FixMbr
>bootrec /FixBoot
Access is denied.
>bootrec /RebuildBcd
Successfully scanned Windows installations.
Total identified Windows installations: 0
The operation completed successfully.
```

As before, I have two drives - either of which can be booted directly by changing the Boot Priority order in the BIOS: either Windows 10 or Windows Server 2012 R2 can be booted directly.

The only Dual Boot option that works is the first (default) to Windows 10. Choosing the second option (Windows Server 2012 R2) leads to this screen:

[Windows Boot failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBgJw.jpg)

My question is interesting IMHO - anyone can build a new OS on a dedicated drive for test purposes and then decide to "integrate" it into a Dual/Triple/... Boot option. My suspicion is that the three **bootrec** commands *only work on single boot drives*. Up to now I have not seen this answered on the internet - all suggest a new install for the second OS to build a Dual Boot option.

**SUCCESS & CONCLUSION:**
see my answer below

Comment: I use EasyBCD to fix these issues, download the free non commercial, no need to register, just hit register, then download button>>>>>https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/#comparison

Comment: thanks. I already had EasyBCD but not the courage to try the repair option. If you add this as an answer I'll give you the green tick mark "solved".

Comment: Is installing GRUB2 and boot from there a option?

Comment: See also this question+answers to install GRUB2 on Windows. https://superuser.com/questions/127509/how-to-install-grub-bootloader-without-installing-linux

Comment: for the next step GRUB will be likely as I want to include Ubuntu in the Boot List options. Thanks.

Comment: @Aendie no need to repair just add server OS to the bootloader, which that software can do, no risk.

Comment: In my experience "*Access is denied*" can be [solved](https://superuser.com/questions/1285268/cannot-boot-windows-10-bootrec-fixboot-gives-access-denied) with [bcdboot](https://web.archive.org/web/20160608045203if_/https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SUCCESS & CONCLUSION:**

I finally dared to try EasyBCD 2.4 with the following steps:

```
BCD Backup/Repair
Backup Settings
Re-create/repair boot files
Perform Action
```

and Dual Boot works now. But why trust a "black box" (meaning EasyBCD) solution? What did it do?

Answer: it changed...

```
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
```

in the default (Windows 10) boot loader to:

```
displaymessageoverride  StartupRepair
```

which suggests that it was fixed by Microsoft "magic". (I admit EasyBCD may have performed other actions too.)

It leaves one question (that I hinted at earlier) unanswered: what if one creates a new single boot OS drive and **later on** decides to integrate it into a Dual Boot option? I have *no idea* how to create a Dual/Triple/... Boot from two or more drives (without reinstalling the second OS). I think this is undocumented(?)

I give credit to **Moab** for the solution, who suggested using EasyBCD.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have a Windows Server install medium, boot from it, and instead of reinstalling Windows Server, choose to Repair. Go to Advanced options, then Command line, and use the "diskpart" set of commands to list your volumes and partitions, just to make sure they're all accounted for.

If that's the case, exit diskpart (type exit and press Enter), then type:

bootrec /fixboot (Enter)

If no error message, type:

bootrec /fixmbr (Enter)

Then:

bootrect /rebuildbcd (Enter)

And exit the installation/repair setup, then reboot.

FWIW, I too have Windows 10 and Windows Server dual-booting on my PC, and my bootloader looks like this, as displayed in EasyBCD (freeware for personal use):

*There are a total of 3 entries listed in the bootloader.

Default: Windows 10

Timeout: 3 seconds

EasyBCD Boot Device: D:\

Entry #1
Name: Windows 10
BCD ID: {current}
Drive: C:\
Bootloader Path: \Windows\system32\winload.exe

Entry #2
Name: Windows Server
BCD ID: {ac735421-add0-11e9-9ef7-e94eceb02e15}
Drive: F:\
Bootloader Path: \Windows\system32\winload.exe

Entry #3
Name: Safe Mode
BCD ID: {ac735424-add0-11e9-9ef7-e94eceb02e15}
Drive: F:\
Bootloader Path: \Windows\system32\winload.exe*

As you can see, the main bootloader is set on the D drive, because that's where I installed Windows 10 AFTER installing Windows Server 2019. Windows 10 installed a secondary bootloader during install.